# How can I make a script wait for a button press?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, wait

I apologize if the answer to this question is obvious, but I am unfamiliar with the inner workings of Python.

Basic Scenario: I have a Python script that does stuff. Periodically, when certain conditions are met (like a flag variable being set), I want the script to pause and wait for the user to press a GUI button.

How can I implement this?

To clarify, I want it to work like input() does, in that it pauses everything and waits for the function call to be resolved, except that I don't want it tied to text, but rather a GUI button. I plan on using Tkinter to make the button.

My initial thoughts are making a while loop something like this:

```
x = 2
while (x > 1):
    #do nothing
```

And then the button will call a function that sets x = 0

Is this the proper way to do this? Is there a better way? Am i missing something obvious?

Sample Code:

```
class Displayable(object):
    max_display_level = 1   # can be overridden in subclasses
    manual_step = False     # can be overridden in subclasses

    def display(self,level,*args,**kwargs):
        -Do stuff unrelated to the question-

        if (self.manual_step):
           if level <= self.max_display_level:
               input("Waiting for input: ")
```

The idea behind this is objects will extend the class Displayable and set their own max_display_level and manual_step values. A higher max_display_level means more messages will be displayed (ie. if I call display() with levels = 1,2,3, and 4, if my max_display_level ==2, only the first 2 calls will have all the logic executed. It is a way to allow a user to set the level of verbosity of the execution. It's there for a reason which I won't get into, but it should stay.) If a specific object has manual_step == true and the level is satisfied, it should wait for user input when display() is called. The trick is I want it to wait for a button press instead of text+enter.

Comment: Busy waiting is not a good practice. Generally you'd want to use something like `time.sleep()` to pause a script (which lets other processes on the system run). That said, also generally, GUIs don't pause, they enter a state where most events are ignored until one that changes the state occurs. Lastly, `tkinter` doesn't support multi-threading itself. It's possible to do non-gui things in threads if you're careful though. I can't be more specific without more details (or sample code) in your question.

Comment: The script is single-threaded, I didn't mean to imply it was multi-threaded. I also don't really care what the "button input" does, as long as it makes everything else wait for it to be resolved/pressed. If you have any ideas I am listening.

Comment: The name of the thing you are asking for is a _modal dialog_. Once displayed, it pauses the GUI until the user responds. There are plenty of examples on the internet of creating modal dialogs in tkinter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're planning on using a GUI button (especially tkinter), you shouldn't need to do anything- GUIs tend to run their own infinite loop dealing with drawing and handling events. The moment you all a .mainloop() for tkinter, nothing after that point in your code will be executed except callbacks and tkinter events; i.e.:

```
root= Tk()
root.mainloop()
print("This won't be printed until root window is closed")
```

Best practice would be to tie the stuff that should happen when the button is pressed to that button as a command/callback. (`Button(master, ... command=callback OR command=lambda *e: callback())`)

To do what you would like, I'd suggest putting a `Button.disable()` at the beginning of longish-running code (so the button doesn't look clickable), and then a `Button.enable()` at the end so you can click it. Or create/show the button to do the next step at the end of the function (creating that button on-the-fly could let you pass results of this function directly into the callback for the next function via lambdas)

```
def cb_1(root_window, btn_to_disable):
    btn_to_disable.disable()
    foo = complex_algorithm()
    # Create a button for the next part
    Button(root_window, text='do cb_2 with foo',
           command=lambda e, arg=foo, r=root_window: cb_2(r, arg)).pack()

def cb_2(root, argument):
    print("This is foo, from cb_1:",argument) # prints foo

root = Tk()
btn = Button(root, text="do cb_1",
             command=lambda *e: cb_1(root, btn))
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
print("This isn't printed until the GUI is closed!")
```

EDIT: As per your newest edit, it seems that `after()` will be your friend - it lets a function schedule itself again through tkinter's mainloop, without blocking the GUI's actions. i.e. in `Displayable`:

```
def display(self, level, *args, **kwargs):
    #unrelated#
    self.wait_for_next(level, *args, **kwargs)

def wait_for_next(self, level, *args, **kwargs)
    if self.manual_step:
       if (level <= self.max_display_level):
           if self.button_set_value:
               # Do something with button-set value
               print('FOO')
           else:
               # set ourselves to re-check after 1000 ms
               self.root.after(1000,
                               lambda *e:self.wait_for_next(level, *args, **kwargs))
```

Presumably, wherever your buttons are, they set some value (or just set a flag). When that value is truthy, this would print `"FOO"`. You will probably call display() again at this point.

Another way to do it would be to simply have `display()` as the callback for the button, so when the button is pressed, `display` is called.

Comment: Seeing your edit I am adding more relevant info soon

Comment: I had to modify your answer slightly. I'm using Jupyter notebooks which for some reason blocks GUI threads if the main process blocks, so I just pushed all the real computation off to a thread and it worked.

Comment: @GreySage good choice, many GUIs don't like to run properly on child threads- it's a generally good idea to outsource computation and leave GUI in the main thread.